# ListResponseMessage of Gmail SDK contains only message ID and no message

Tags: java, gmail-api, message

I have just started using Gmail SDK.

I am trying to get all the mail messages from my Gmail account. I tried using this:

```
ListMessagesResponse response = gmail.users().messages().list(user).execute();
List<Message> messages = response.getMessages();
```

The problem here is when I try to access the **snippet** using the code below I get **null**.

```
for(Message message : messages) {
    System.out.println(message.getSnippet());
}
```

On the other hand I am being to get to **messageId** when I try this:

```
for(Message message : messages) {
    System.out.println(message.getId());
}
```

**My query is that am I doing something wrong or is it supposed to return only the messageId?**

I have another function to which if you pass a particular messageId returns the message. Using this method I am able to get the **Snippet** and works perfectly fine.

```
private Message getMessage(String userId, String messageId) throws IOException {
        Message message = gmail.users().messages().get(userId, messageId).execute();
        System.out.println("Message snippet: " + message.getSnippet());
        return message;
    }
```

**Do I have to call this method everytime to get each message? Is there not a way to get all the messages at once?**

Comment: Is `Message` your own code? If so please show.

Comment: You can bring it down to 2 total requests by using [batch requests](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch). There is support for that in the Java client library.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Message is not my own code. It is part of the Gmail API. `com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message`

Comment: @Tholle Batching the requests is surely an excellent approach but still wouldn't I require the messageId first to get the message?

Comment: @amitection Yes, you are correct. You would have to get a page of ids, and then a second request to get all those messages in batch.